How to force specific tabs in Chrome extensions to use proxy?
I'm developing a Chrome extension that uses a PAC script to route traffic through a SOCKS5 proxy for a specific domain, let's say a.com.
Here is my PAC script:
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host === 'a.com') {
        return "SOCKS5 1.2.3.4:1080";
    }
    return "DIRECT";
}

The PAC script successfully proxies requests directly to a.com, but any requests made by a.com to other domains (e.g., b.com) do not go through the proxy and instead use a direct connection.
I also can't use any storage inside the PAC script, so I think it might not be the right way to solve my problem.
I'd like to develop an extension that provides the possibility to use a proxy on specific tabs and save this setting to storage, so when I reopen the site, it would use the proxy.
How can I achieve this without using chrome.proxy?
